# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found YII

Tags: yii

Relations of review below:

```
return array(
        'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'product_id'),
        'profile' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Profile', 'profile_id'),
        'rating' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Rating', 'rating_id'),
        'reviewcomments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Reviewcomment', 'review_id'),
        'reviewhelpfuls' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Reviewhelpful', 'review_id'),
                    'commentCounts' => array(self::STAT, 'Reviewcomment', 'review_id'),
    );
```

Controller code below:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
           $criteria->addCondition("t.seoUrl = :seoUrl");
           $criteria->addCondition("t.published = 1");
           $criteria->params = array("seoUrl"=>$seoUrl);               
           $data['product'] = Product::model()->find($criteria);
           if($data['product']){
                $data['product']->hits = $data['product']->hits+1;
                $data['product']->save();
           } else{
               throw new CHttpException(404, "Invalid Request for product");
           }
           $product_id = $data['product']->id;
           $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
           $criteria->addCondition("t.product_id = '$product_id'");

           if(isset($_GET['rating']))
           {
               $rating_id = $_GET['rating'];
               $criteria->addCondition("t.rating_id = '$rating_id'");
           }           


           $criteria->addCondition('t.status = "approved"');

           if(isset($_GET['sort']))
           {
               $sorting = $_GET['sort'];
               if($sorting=='newest')
                   $criteria->order = "t.postDate DESC";
               elseif($sorting=='oldest')
                   $criteria->order = "t.postDate ASC";
               elseif($sorting=='rating_high')
                   $criteria->order = "t.rating_id DESC";
               elseif($sorting=='rating_low')
                   $criteria->order = "t.rating_id ASC";
           }

           $data['reviews'] = new CActiveDataProvider('Review', array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'pagination'=>array('pagesize'=>4)

            ));
```

Now when I am running this code, I am getting CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.rating_id' in 'where clause'

Thanks for your help

Comment: i think you have to check column name, it must be something else than `rating_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Intstead of using 't' as alias for your tables, start using `getTableAlias(false, false)`
In your case it would be:

```
$criteria->addCondition(Review::model()->getTableAlias(false, false).".rating_id = '$rating_id'");
```

More importantly this code screams SQL injection

```
$rating_id = $_GET['rating'];
$criteria->addCondition("t.rating_id = '$rating_id'");
```

Never use user input without processing it. Yii allows you to bind values which would be escaped for you - no threat of SQL injection(atleast as far as i know). You should be creating your criteria like so:

```
$criteria->addCondition(Review::model()->getTableAlias(false, false).".rating_id = :rating_id");
$criteria->params = array(
    ':rating_id' => $rating_id,
);
```